# Delete Facebook account including chat

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there any possible way to delete a Facebook account including all old chat messages **both sides**, I know I can delete my Facebook account (comments, likes, groups...) but what to do about old chat?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete messages from someone else's inbox. Deleting account will not delete messages from recipient's inbox. But your name or profile link will not be there once account is deleted. It will show 'Facebook user' instead of your name.